# One Game Center for 2 different apps

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

Is it possible to have 2 apps and make both of them use the same Leaderboard on Game Center?

I have a game in its lite and paid version and I want to know if I can implement Game Center Leaderboards but without having to separate the leaderboard for the ones who have the lite and the ones who have the paid version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possibly, I solved it by just adding the same app to the same Group of Game Center at iTunes Connect

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible from my experience doing this.

I would usually create a single app that is free to download and unlock the premium content via an in app purchase. This would mean you could use the same leaderboard for both paying and non paying players.

maybe it is possible using a wild card app id? (Ive never tried ) but i doubt it would work and if it did you may have trouble adding in app purchases or push notifications that require an explicit app id.

good luck with your game